# Visual Studios Code can't debug

Tags: python, visual-studio

Since I updated Visual Studios Code about a week ago I'm experiencing problems within the program. For example, I can't use the built-in debug feature. When I try to, nothing happens but an error message pops up at the top saying:

> Debug adapter process has terminated unexpectedly.

Also, when you right-click on a .py file and press "Run Python File in Terminal" literally nothing happens. I can still run the files by clicking on them outside of VSCode, so there shouldn't be anything wrong with the programs itself. Unlike other similar questions, I have not installed Xdebug, but I do have Git installed. It doesn't matter whether I have created an repository or not. I have tried uninstalling VSCode and installing it again, without success.

Comment: [Visual Studio Code (VSCode) - Error: Debug Adapter Process Has Terminated Unexpectedly](//stackoverflow.com/q/40078738)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio Code (VSCode) - Error: Debug Adapter Process Has Terminated Unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40078738/visual-studio-code-vscode-error-debug-adapter-process-has-terminated-unexpe)